How to extract a small segment of H264 stream from a complete H264 stream?
I cut a large image into many tiles (150,000), and then encoded it into a .h264 file with FFmpeg at one frame per second and put it on the server. Now I want to randomly decode a picture from the .h264 file for analysis.
My idea for decoding locally is to record their indexes (i, j) when cutting the pictures, and then let the decoder find the corresponding frame in .h264 according to the index, and the effect is pretty good.
Now I put .h264 on the server (minio), and I want to intercept only a section of the code stream and decode it. Is this possible?
（For example, my .h264 has 10 frames in total, and I want to decode the 5th frame and save it. Can I cache the 4th to 6th frames and then decode them?）
----------------------This is the code I used to capture a small portion of the stream from the server.-----------------------------------------------------------
@lru_cache(1024)
def read_small_cached(self, start, length, retry=5):
    ''' read cached and thread safe, but do not read too large'''
    if length == 0:
        return b''
    resp = None
    for _ in range(retry):
        try:
            _client = minio_get_client()
            resp = _client.get_object(
                self.bucket, self.filename, offset=start, length=length)
            oup = resp.read()
            return oup
        except:
            time.sleep(3)
        finally:
            if resp is not None:
                resp.close()
                resp.release_conn()
    raise Exception(f'can not read {self.name}')


I tried parameters such as start = 0, length = 10241024100, and I can read part of the picture.
But when I used the function to find IDR frames and get their position, FFmpeg's decoder thought it was an invalid resource.
---here is my find key_frame 's code-
def get_all_content(file_path, search_bytes):

if not file_path or not search_bytes:
    raise ValueError("file_path 和 search_bytes 不能为空")

search_len = len(search_bytes)
positions = []

with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
    fp.seek(0, 2)  # 移动到文件末尾 0表示文件移动的字节数，2表示到末尾，这样是为了获取文件的总大小
    file_size = fp.tell()  # 文件大小
    fp.seek(0)  # 回到文件开始

    pos = 0
    while pos <= (file_size - search_len):
        fp.seek(pos)
        buf = fp.read(search_len)
        if len(buf) < search_len:
            break
        if buf == search_bytes:
            positions.append(pos)
        pos += 1

return positions

I have only recently started to understand H264. Perhaps I have a misunderstanding of bitstream and H264. I hope to get some guidance. Thanks in advance!

How to find a frame means you check every start-code in the h264 data until you have counted enough to reach your frame. A start-code is 3 bytes of 00 00 01... It's not clear what h264 data you got from FFmpeg. Maybe share your FFmpeg commands? If you chose to make every frame as a keyframe, then you can simply scan the output file for positions of keyframes. A keyframe will start as 4 bytes of 00 00 01 65 (but the 6 could be a 2 or a 4, it depends on your FFmpeg output settings).

PS... (1) Practice with a small image (16x16 resolution). Convert to H264 then analyse those bytes. (2) Analyse the H264 file with a hex editor to know what the code sees when it reads your file. (3) Learn how to convert hex into decimals using Python (eg: why does hex FF convert to being decimal 255?)....  To display a frame: First, you need metadata of SPS and then PPS. Secondly now you can add a keyframe's bytes. Such a file will display in a media player like VLC. Practice in hex editor to know what byte comes after a start-code of 00 00 01, that byte tells you the data type.

this is my ffmpeg command. ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input_images.txt -c:v libx264 -qp 29 -pix_fmt yuvr420p -r 1  video_file
input_images.txt is the frames' path

i've solved my problem,thankyou!
